# Laplace's law derivation

Tags: pressure

I'm reading a biology paper which uses [LaPlace's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ptens.html) in the analysis. Basically the tension within a spherical pressure vessel is half the product of the radius and pressure. I'm trying to understand how this equation is derived but don't have a strong background in fluids or physics so I'm not really understanding the general process. Could anyone give a more general overview description?

In my undergrad we learned about [thin-walled pressure vessels](https://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/mat_mechanics/pressure_vessel.cfm), and how the tension within these is a function of radius, pressure, and thickness. How does this fit into LaPlace's law?